# Why do we use Multichannel AEC when tweaking the tap length of Simple AEC can cancellation multiple echoes?

Tags: noise-cancellation, multi-channel

We are working on Acoustic Echo Cancellation. For that we have performed different experiments and we got to the conclusion that if we are getting multiple echoes in the Near-end signal, we can cancel all these echo ripples by setting the tap length = max number of delayed samples of echo ripple. If setting the tap length of simple AEC can serve the purpose for us, why do we need Multi-channel AEC ?

Answer (score 0):

Multi channel echo cancellation typically refers to the case where you have more than reference signal.

An example would be a Home Theater Sound bar with a build-in voice assistant rendering 5.1 channel content. The AEC is supposed to remove the content from the microphone inputs, but each microphone sees content from all 5 input channels, so you need to estimate a transfer function from each channel (or transducer) to each microphone)

Comment: Could you please explain the term "reference signal" here? Does it mean that the reference signals are different? What if we are playing same signal from each speaker? Because if we are playing same signal then I have tested that longer taplength can cancel all the echoes. In such case why should we use or what is the need of using multichannel AEC?

Comment: If every speaker plays the same signal (or signals that are derived from a single original signal), than you don't need multi-channel echo cancellation

Comment: Then how can we cater non-uniqueness problem in this case?

Comment: What is non-unique here?

Comment: Same signals being played from each speaker. AEC will not converge due to coherence among the signals

Comment: As long as all speaker signals are derived from the same input and the transfer functions are strictly LTI, the AEC can still converge. Decoherence only comes for time-variances, non-linarites, excessive reverberation, etc. Whether multi-channel helps here or not depends on the specific root cause of the decoherence.

Comment: In our case, there are multiple smartphones, and all smartphones are playing the same audio signal with the synchronization accuracy of 3ms. In this case, multiple echo paths and multiple reverberations occur. 
This resembles surround systems but here the smartphones are connected, forming a cluster of smartphones in a distributed manner.
Now keeping this scenario in mind, where smartphones somewhat speakers show nonlinear behavior, Will it be considered as a multichannel AEC issue or a single AEC with the long tap-length issue?

Comment: The length of  your AEC is simply a function of the impulse response of your room. The non-linearity of the speakers decorrelate the signals which makes it a multi-channel problem. If the non-linearity is primarily due to software (limiter, clipper, compressor), you can use the actual transducer signals as references for the AEC. If the transducer itself is non-linear, you have a very difficult problem to solve. That's the a reason why  Amazon Echo (and similar) use more linear (and expensive) transducers than you would typically find in this class of product.

Comment: Yes. I know that Tap-length is directly related to room impulse response. What I am not sure is about the characteristics of Smartphone Speakers. 
Since we are using Android devices (low end and high end) then I assume that there might be non-linearity in the phones' speakers.
Since we haven't got any extra transducer, we are stuck to use smartphone mics and speakers. We cant use external devices here.
What I have understood from your answer is that if the signals are coherent, then it is simple AEC with long tap length problem else it is multichannel problem. Right?

Comment: IF the phones are reasonably linear AND if the phones  are not moving AND if they all play the same content, than it's still a single channel AEC. However, it's very tricky one, since the channel is VERY complicated, i.e. $M(\omega) = \sum_k H_k(\omega) X(\omega)$ where each $H_k(\omega)$ is a room transfer function which is long and complicated.

Comment: I am not sure if the phones speakers are reasonably linear or not. In our case, 90% of the times, phones will be at static position.
Since all phones are playing same content at approximately same time(+- 3ms), and mobile phones are eventually placed in closed proximity. Now in this case, multiple impulse response pair will be created. Echoes might be overlapping with different echo paths. Will a single AEC cancel all these echoes? (Assuming we set up a long tap-length)

Comment: I've read in different articles that most of the times behavior of speaker is non-linear (at higher amplitudes) So how is a single tap length in Single channel AEC cancelling all the echoes?

Comment: I agree, smart phone speakers tend to be fairly non-linear. If you have significant non-linear distortion, conventional linear AEC will not work. Multi-channel linear AEC will not work either.

Comment: What we have tested the combination of built-in hardware AEC on the smartphone and software AEC(WebRTC AEC) is cancelling all the echoes. We are also using RN Noise with transferred learning to remove any residual echo. This combination is somewhat giving us echoless communication. Now my point here is if echoes are being cancelled using one or two single tap- length AECs in cascaded way then how does it become a multi-channel problem and what I've read is that in multi-channel there is still a coherence among the channels which is being differentiated using decorrelation methods.